# Observable Collection issue in Xamarin PCL

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

Xamarin PCL doesnt seem to have Observable Collections when referencing system.collections.objectmodel.  Strange thing is when watching a MvvmCross tutorial it showed the use of such a collection in a view model within a PCL.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtXXmS3oHHY around the 13mins mark.

Is it because I'm using Xamarin Studio as opposed to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

ObservableCollection is in the System.Windows assembly - it is available in Xamarin in PCLs as long as you:

- target a profile that includes it (e.g. 104)
- and as long as you include a reference to the System.Windows reference assembly